# Hystrix dashboard - charts are not displayed

Tags: javascript, netflix, hystrix

Im using hystrix dashboard from maven repo
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.hystrix/hystrix-dashboard
I deployed was file into fresh tomcat, tomcat is starting without erros.

Im did the same with 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.hystrix/hystrix-examples-webapp
which generating a hystrix stream correclty.

after I configure stream i get this screen:

[image]

in chrome console I see:
Connection was closed on error: [object Event]

and I stuck, because when I go to .../hystrix.stream i can see that stream is generating correctly.

I think charts should be showed even if stream is empty/not working, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

I should use tomcat 7 instead of tomcat 8.